# Derivation of power method

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**POWER METHOD**

1. Let $x_0$ be an initial approximation to the eigenvector.
2. For $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ do

   1. Compute $x_k=Ax_{k-1}$,
   2. Normalize $x_k=x_k/\|x_k\|_\infty$.

Then $\|x_k\|_\infty$ approaches the dominant eigenvalue and $x_k$ approaches the corresponding eigenvector  of the matrix $A$.

**My question**: But why?

**A part of an answer shared by all numerical books**: If the eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ associated with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are linearly independent, we can write
$$x_0=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n$$

Multiplying both sides by $A^k$ gives

$$\begin{align}
A^Kx_0 &=A^k(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n)\\
       &=c_1\lambda_1^k v_1+c_2\lambda_2^k v_2+\cdots+c_n\lambda_n^k v_n\\
       &=\lambda_1^k \left( c_1v_1+c_2 \left(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right)^k v_2+\cdots+\left(\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_1}\right)^k v_n \right)
\end{align}$$

Since the $\lambda_1$ is the dominant eigenvalue, i.e. $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_i|$ for each $i$, $\left( \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Then

$$
A^k x_0=\lambda_1^k c_1 v_1
$$

Up to this point, there is no problem. After reading many books, I couldn't find a clear and general proof for after this point.

**I found a new hint, but yet why?:** Of course we don't have $\lambda_1$ available but virtually any homogeneous scaling
of $A^k x_0$ that is proportional to $\lambda_1^k$ will do. [[Jack J. Dongarra](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fq1mNXw32u4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=numerical%20linear%20algebra%20for%20high-performance%20computers&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jf8dVOHTDIKaO5vGgDg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Of%20course%20we%20don't%20have%22%20%22available%20but%20virtually%20any%20homogeneous%20scaling%20of%22%20%22that%20is%20proportional%20to%22%20%22will%20do.%22&f=false)]

**Extra question:** Why am I stupid?

Comment: I think you mean $(\lambda_i/\lambda_1)\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: You have the whole proof, except that you need to apply the normalization step.

Comment: Actually, stating $A^k x_0 = \lambda_1^k c_1 v_1$ is a problem.  Unless you have a really special $A$, this is not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

It's a litle confusing that you call ${\bf x_k}$ both the unnormalized and the normalized vector. Let's call ${\bf y_k} $ the normalized vector. We agree that, as $k\to \infty$

$${\bf x_k}=A^k {\bf x_0}=\lambda_1^k c_1 {\bf v_1}$$

Actually, this would correspond to the procedure without normalization. But the normalization would just multiply each ${\bf x_k}$ by some scalar, then we should actually write

$$ {\bf y_k} = \alpha \lambda_1^k c_1 {\bf v_1} = \beta {\bf v_1} $$

But this means that ${\bf y_k} $ is a multiple of the dominant eigenvector... then it's a (dominant) eigenvector. The same goes for ${\bf x_k} $.

Then $${\bf x_{k+1}} = A {\bf y_{k}} = \lambda_1 {\bf y_{k}} = \lambda_1 \frac{{\bf x_{k}}}{|{\bf x_{k}}|}$$

Then, because as $k$ grows ${\bf x_{k+1}} \approx {\bf x_{k}}$ we must have $\lambda_1 = |{\bf x_{k}}|$

Comment: Is $\beta = \alpha \lambda_1^k c_1 $ ?

Answer (score 0):

After including normalization, you should get that
$$ v:= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{A^kx_0}{\lambda_1^k} = \pm \frac{v_1}{||v_1||} .$$

Hence $v$ is some constant multiple of $v_1$, and is therefore an eigenvector itself.  Being a constant multiple of $v_1$ implies $v$ and $v_1$ have the same associated eigenvalue-- in this case, the dominant eigenvalue $\lambda_1$.

For the record, I extracted this from *A Friendly Introduction to Numerical Analysis* by Brian Bradie.  It's an excellent book.

Comment: I read that book. It's good, but not excellent. It's very similar to Numerical Analysis by Burden. Unfortunately I could not understand what Bradie said about this problem.

Comment: Do you understand my restatement?  Bradie's proof is very thorough.  What is the piece you're missing?

Comment: I cannot find any relationship between $\lambda_1^k$ and $\|Ax_k\|_\infty$

Comment: You have the relationship.  It's in your problem statement.

Comment: To get down to the level of precision that I think you're after, you'd have to look at things component-wise.  Bradie a priori defines an algorithm that keeps track of which component of $Ax_k$ gives the infinity-norm of $Ax_k$.  He then shows that this sequence of components converges to $\lambda_1$, thus resulting in $v$ being a unit vector.  If you still have his book, I'd recommend combing through that paragraph again; if not, I'll post it in my own words.